# Magento 2 admin customer grid export to csv with custom fields

Tags: magento2, customer, grid, export, uicomponent

I need to modify the columns in the customer csv file generated by the Ui module in magento 2.
 The problem is that the csv file is generated in a generic class of Ui Module, and not from the customer module.
Also the data is generated  from the Ui component data provider class so  the data in the CSV depends on the columns from the Ui component XML.
Also, i need to keep the customer grid columns intact.

Is there any other way to inject/remove the columns from the CSV file?

Comment: make sure before export the newly added column is show in grid it export the column which shows in in grid only

Comment: How to solve this?